# How to do resume parsing in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm riswana new to Codeigniter. And I'm trying to find out how to do parsing in Codeigniter? I've got a task: to do parsing with some piece of unknown for me symbols and put it to DB. I guess I can create DB and tables with help of mysql, but I have no idea how to do parsing and what all these symbols below mean?

Comment: I am unable to get your question. Please provide some details.

Comment: check my answer for parsing with templates in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

You can read file using file_get_contents like below :

```
<?php
$filedata = file_get_contents('filepath');
echo $filedata;
?>
```

Using CURL

```
<?php
  $url = "yourfilepath";
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: you need to read that file and explode the words and store that into database

Comment: I think ther is no library for read ".doc" file. you can use php function file_get_contents()

Comment: Try to using CURL. For how to use CURL see my updated answer.

Comment: make sure in your server CURL is enabled

Comment: no need to convert into xml. just remain as .doc file and read through curl

Comment: your .doc file location

Comment: check your file permission. may be permission issue

Comment: how can i explode the document?